# is it possible to deploy vault ha cluster with minio as storage backend

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

is it possible to deploy hashicorp vault ha cluster with minio as storage backend ? I could see that Google cloud storage is supported with HA. I am trying to deploy HA vault in K8s cluster